# Update ObservableCollection when Firestore event occurs

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Xamarin Forms to create a cross-platform application. I have decided to use Firestore as the database for my app.

I am trying to add chat functionality to my app using and I'm struggling with implementing the real-time listening functionality. I have already created a ViewModel class containing an ObservableCollection of Chats that is used by a ListView in the UI.

```
public class ChatsVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Chat> Chats { get; set; }

    public ChatsVM()
    {
        Chats = new ObservableCollection<Chat>();
        ReadMessages();
    }

    public async void ReadMessages()
    {
        User currentUser = await DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthenticationService>().GetCurrentUserProfileAsync();
        IList<Chat> chatList = await DependencyService.Get<IChatService>().GetChatsForUserAndListenAsync(currentUser.IsLandlord, currentUser.Id);

        foreach (var chat in chatList)
        {
            Chats.Add(chat);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also created the services to fetch the data from Firestore. On the service side of things (example is showing Android service) I am using a standard List to hold Chat objects

```
List<Chat> Chats;
bool hasReadChats;
```

The method GetChatsForUserAndListenAsync adds a snapshot listener to my query and passes events to the OnEvent method.

```
public async Task<IList<Chat>> GetChatsForUserAndListenAsync(bool isLandlord, string userId)
    {
        string fieldToSearch;

        if (isLandlord)
        {
            fieldToSearch = "landlordId";
        }
        else
        {
            fieldToSearch = "tenantId";
        }

        try
        {
            // Reset the hasReadChats value.
            hasReadChats = false;
            CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection(Constants.Chats);
            // Get all documents in the collection and attach a OnCompleteListener to
            // provide a callback function.
            collectionReference.WhereEqualTo(fieldToSearch, userId).AddSnapshotListener(this);

            // Wait until the callback has finished reading and formatting the returned
            // documents.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
                // If the callback has finished, continue rest of the execution.
                if (hasReadChats)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return Chats;
        }
        catch (FirebaseFirestoreException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("An unknown error occurred. Please try again.");
        }
    }

public void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object value, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
    {
        var snapshot = (QuerySnapshot) value;

        if (!snapshot.IsEmpty)
        {
            var documents = snapshot.Documents;
            Chats.Clear();

            foreach (var document in documents)
            {
                Chat chat = new Chat
                {
                    Id = document.Id,
                    LandlordId = document.Get("landlordId") != null ? document.Get("landlordId").ToString() : "",
                    TenantId = document.Get("tenantId") != null ? document.Get("tenantId").ToString() : ""
                };
                //JavaList messageList = (JavaList) document.Get("messages");
                //List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();

                // chat.Messages = messages;

                Chats.Add(chat);
            }
            hasReadChats = true;
        }
    }
```

How would I propagate any changes to this list that are made by the event handler to the ObservableCollection in my VM class?

Comment: use MessagingCenter to send a message from Android to the Forms VM that contains any new messages

Comment: That's not a bad idea at all. But I need to pass objects. Would it be efficient to pass a message whenever an event is triggered on the database and get the VM class to re-read the list?

Comment: you can pass a strongly typed parameter with the message

Comment: ok, I'll give that a go and let you know how it goes. Thanks Jason!

Comment: Great solution @Jason. Did exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @splinter-cell, could you please add an answer with the changes you had to make in order to fix this so other people with the same issue and find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Jason for suggesting this answer.

So I modified the event handler to look for document changes in Firestore. Based on these changes, the service would send different messages using MessagingCenter.

```
public async void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object value, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
    {
        var snapshot = (QuerySnapshot) value;

        if (!snapshot.IsEmpty)
        {
            var documentChanges = snapshot.DocumentChanges;
            IFirebaseAuthenticationService firebaseAuthenticationService = DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthenticationService>();
            Chats.Clear();
            
            foreach (var documentChange in documentChanges)
            {
                var document = documentChange.Document;
        
                string memberOne = document.Get(Constants.MemberOne) != null ? document.Get(Constants.MemberOne).ToString() : "";
                string memberTwo = document.Get(Constants.MemberTwo) != null ? document.Get(Constants.MemberTwo).ToString() : "";
                
                Chat chat = new Chat
                {
                    Id = document.Id,
                    MemberOne = memberOne,
                    MemberTwo = memberTwo,
                };

                var documentType = documentChange.GetType().ToString();

                switch (documentType)
                {
                    case Constants.Added:
                        MessagingCenter.Send<IChatService, Chat>(this, Constants.Added, chat);
                        break;
                    case Constants.Modified:
                        MessagingCenter.Send<IChatService, Chat>(this, Constants.Modified, chat);
                        break;
                    case Constants.Removed:
                        MessagingCenter.Send<IChatService, Chat>(this, Constants.Removed, chat);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
               
                Chats.Add(chat);
            }
            hasReadChats = true;
        }
    }
```

In the constructor for the VM, I subscribed as a listener for these messages and updated the ObservableCollection accordingly.

```
public class ChatsVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Chat> Chats { get; set; }

    public ChatsVM()
    {
        Chats = new ObservableCollection<Chat>();
        ReadChats();
    }

    public async void ReadChats()
    {
        IFirebaseAuthenticationService firebaseAuthenticationService = DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthenticationService>();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IChatService, Chat>(this, Constants.Added, (sender, args) =>
        {
            Chat chat = args;
            Chats.Add(chat);
        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IChatService, Chat>(this, Constants.Modified, (sender, args) =>
        {
            Chat updatedChat = args;
            Chats.Any(chat =>
            {
                if (chat.Id.Equals(updatedChat.Id))
                {
                    int oldIndex = Chats.IndexOf(chat);
                    Chats.Move(oldIndex, 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IChatService, Chat>(this, Constants.Removed, (sender, args) =>
        {
            Chat removedChat = args;
            Chats.Any(chat =>
            {
                if (chat.Id.Equals(removedChat.Id))
                {
                    Chats.Remove(chat);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        
        User currentUser = await firebaseAuthenticationService.GetCurrentUserProfileAsync();
        await DependencyService.Get<IChatService>().GetChatsForUserAndListenAsync(currentUser.Id);
    }
}
```